# Area 51 Security Review Proposal

Tags: discussion

Stack Overflow has Code Review. UX is about to have Design Review.

So what do we need? Security Review. Someone needs to start a proposal to make such a site happen.

Comment: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/10143/27680

Comment: [chat] is a better place to discuss this first

Answer (score -3):

## Here it is.

After (some) deliberation, I've started a proposal doing just that. Here it is.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54083/security-review